# which windows service is responsible for the mouse?

Tags: mouse, windows-services

Is there a service responsible for controling the mouse?   I want to try stop/starting it after making a few control panel changes via the registry.

(I need to get the changes to apply witout rebooting because rebooting just resets them back to default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mouse isn't controlled by a service. Its function is managed by a device driver. See the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mouhid`. If you run `DRIVERQUERY.EXE`, you'll see that it runs as part of the kernel and doesn't have its own process id. As such, I'd doubt that it can be stopped or killed.

Comment: @MrVimes: If it's listed in services, you can just set the Start value of mouhid to 4 to disable it at boot, but I'm unsure if your computer can still boot then. Maybe you could try `net stop mouhid` and `net start mouhid`, but again, I don't know the consequences of this. Anyway, I think this won't help with your other question: http://superuser.com/questions/180541/is-it-possible-to-apply-a-registry-change-without-rebooting

Answer (score 1):

As noted by BillP3rd, mice are handled by a kernel driver, not by a service.

However, drivers are too managed by the Service Controller and can be controlled by `sc` or `net start`.

*(`sc stop beep` to kill the PC speaker is a classic.)*

Comment: While `SC STOP BEEP` works, and while `SC QUERY MOUCLASS` would seem to indicate that the driver can be stopped, `SC STOP MOUCLASS` generates the error `[SC] ControlService FAILED 1052: The requested control is not valid for this service.` (The driver `mouhid` referenced above isn't actually running on my system.)